# Earned more rep in a day than in a week?

Tags: support, reputation

[image: Apparently I'm more awesome than I thought.]

I guess I'm just talented.

Comment: Did you downvote yesterday?

Comment: @mmyers: Come to think of it, i did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got +35 today, and had -1 somewhere in the previous days of the week by downvoting someone.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible if you lost reputation during the week. In this case, I think it is most likely that you downvoted a post. That would mean today you got 35 rep, but the net total for the week is 34.

There are, of course, other combinations that are somewhat less likely. For example, you could have gotten +5 from an upvoted question, +10 from an upvoted answer, and -16 from eight downvotes on one of your questions or answers. Basically, anything that would cause a net effect of -1 rep during the other days of the week and +35 today could lead to this.