# More rep today than this week?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I noticed something odd just now. Apparently I've accumulated more rep today (20) than I have all week (16).

I found [another question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86488/1588) which asks the same question, with the answer being that the user had downvoted/had been downvoted another day that week, thus losing rep.

My problem with this answer, in this case, is two-fold:

First, I'm pretty sure (but am oddly having issues confirming) that SO weeks start on Monday, so "today" and "this week" should cover the same period.

Second, my reputation tab isn't showing any "downvote events" within the last week that could cause this. `/reputation` also lacks record any such events, though it does show that my displayed rep is horribly out of sync with my real rep. I'm delaying a recalc for the moment in case it's relevant to this question.

I'm at a loss to explain this. Anyone have a theory?

Comment: At least at tex.stackexchange, weeks start on Sunday.

Comment: @lockstep My mistake. That only takes care of the first point though, not the second. The rep page and `/reputation` still don't show any reason why the week rep would be lower than the today rep

Comment: Theory (probably wrong): two of your questions which you accepted answers on got deleted, so you lost 2×2 rep points from the accepts.

Comment: @DanielFischer Interesting theory, but I'm not sure it's accurate. It would explain why `/reputation` has my rep about 300 lower than my display rep, but in that case you would expect my "weekly rep" to also be off by those points lost from question votes. This only seems accurate if two questions of mine were deleted (by a mod, since I haven't done it lately), and both questions had no votes but had accepted answers. Still, it's plausible.

Comment: @DanielFischer I skimmed over my question history (I don't have  many, so I thought I might have a chance at picking out missing ones), and I did notice at least one question gone for moderation reasons. It was noticeable since I'd got the Good/Notable Question badges (for 25+ score and 2500 views, respectively) for it. While I'd tried to kill the question myself before, since a) it was asked before prog.SX opened (from 2008) and no longer belonged on SO, and b) the question was "should i find a new career" and was the main reason I wouldn't want to use SO Careers, I find myself missing it.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far to call it plausible, but it's not entirely impossible. I'm curious what's really behind it, though. The question you found missing can't be it, because that'd lose a lot more question rep.

Comment: @AgentConundrum - Daniel is correct, removed questions like that reverse the accepted vote immediately (causes other possibly bugs if it's still there), up/down votes are synced on rep recalc...and soon they'll be constantly in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of many rep inconsistencies until recalc that were present in the old system.  [The new reputation system already deployed on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) keeps all of this in sync now.

Comment: With the new system now live, I can see that it was a deleted question. I do wish it had been migrated rather than deleted, but apparently old questions don't get moved, as I was told on that question when I self-flagged it as off-topic so very long ago.